# How to interact with objects/variables from another function/method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to Destroy the impact particles after the Target (In this case an explosive barrel) explodes.
But I get the "The name 'impactParticle' does not exist in the current context" error.

I understand that I cannot interact with impactParticle from "void Die();" but is there a way to make the particle system/object public so that other methods can mention it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public Camera fpsCam;
    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    public GameObject impactEffect;
    
   


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

   public void Shoot()
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
            }
            GameObject impactParticle = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
            Destroy(impactParticle, 5f);

        }
    }


    public void Die()
    {
        Destroy(impactParticle);
    }
}
```

I am adding this other script just in case;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 50f;
    public GameObject explode;

    public void TakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;
        if (health <= 0f)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        GameObject PartClone = Instantiate(explode, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
        
        PartClone.SetActive(true);

        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        Destroy(PartClone, 2f);
        Destroy(gameObject, 2.1f);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making `impactParticle` a class level variable:

```
private GameObject _impactParticle;
```

And instantiating it as below:

```
_impactParticle = Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
```

then you can have access to the object in `Die` method:

```
public void Die()
{
    if (_impactParticle != null)
    {
        Destroy(_impactParticle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did and the errors are gone but The particles still don't disappear (The die function is called from another script) How do I fix that ?

Comment: First, check to see if the `Die` method is called correctly (e.g. write a log entry to see when it is called).  If `Die` is called correctly, Then the problem should be in your `Destroy` method.

Comment: It is called correctly in the other script (Target.cs) it works as intended there, but can functions work through scripts? 
Edit: I added the other script as well

Comment: I don't see any reference to your `Gun` class in your `Target` class. meaning the `Die` method is never called in your `Target` class.

Comment: You mean like `Gun.Die();` in the `Target` class?

Comment: Yes. Something like that. you have to have a reference to `Gun` **instance** in your `Target` class if you want to call its `Die` method.

Comment: That gives me another error; `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Gun.Die()'`

Comment: That's why I said **Instance**. you have to have reference access to an instance of `Gun` you're using. you cannot call `Die` method of `Gun` like a static method. Unfortunately, to further help you, I have to inspect your code solution-wide. But in general, You have to somehow pass an instance of `Gun` that you're using to `Target` class (e.g. in `Target` constructor, accept an instance of `Gun` and when you're creating `Target` class, pass the `Gun` instance to the ctor.)

Comment: And how do I do that? English isn't my first language so when it combines with code that I don't know it becomes really complicated. May I ask you to link a tutorial or explain it in a simpler language? If it isn't much to ask I mean.

Comment: I wish I could help you more. But I don't know how and when you create these classes. your `Target` ctor would be something like `public Target(Gun gun)` and when you create `Target` you have to have access to your `Gun` object. so when you create `Target` you call: `var target = new Target(gun)` where `gun` is an object you created before. You can google `Parameterized Constructor in C#`  for more information. Hope this helps.